# Finding P Value of Two sample hypotesis test for Proportion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, proportion

I am attempting to find the P-value of a hypothesis test, which compares the success rate of two procedures. A test with 0.05 level of significance is conducted to test the success rate of two procedures.

**Procedure A**
Sample Size: 200,
Number of Success: 125

**Procedure B**
Sample Size: 100,
Number of Success: 55

**My Attempt**

> [image]

The cooprrect p-val in the ans key is 0.2113. Appreciate some guidiance on where Ive gone wrong

Comment: I wonder if the answer key has a typo (if I just did it right, I think it should be nearer to 0.213). Another possibility might be if a continuity correction was used.

Comment: Thank you for your continual help Glen. May I seek your advice if my steps are on the right path?

Comment: They look okay to me.